# Is there a way to connect to SQL server through windows authentication without using Integrated Security=true option from java

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I want to connect to a SQL server using windows username and password through Java eclipse

Able to connect with Integrated Security = true .

But need try with other domains.

connecting with the below connection URL.

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://servername;databaseName=database;integratedSecurity=true"
```

Jar - MsSQL-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar

failed with this URL

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://servername;databaseName=database;user=domain\user;password=password"
```

Error Message

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user
>   'domain\User'. ClientConnectionId:df0fd280-7727-446f-96e4-ce972fda26d7
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
>     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5036)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3668)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:94)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3627)
>     at 
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7194)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2935)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2456)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2103)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1950)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1162)
>     at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:735)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   sql.Javaconnection.main(Javaconnection.java:27)

Comment: What you're looking for here is called impersonation. You can't supply a username and password in the connection string when using integrated authentication; that's for using SQL Authentication. Impersonation is handled in the application, not the connection manager, so you'll need to let people know what code library your using (C#, java?) and provide the code your using to create/connect to your SQL Instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same option is for .NET. The answer is NO.

Comment: So the applications I have with impersonation in .net are a lie? You can't set this up in the connection string alone, but you can still use a different AD account to your own to connect; it's just got a few extra steps.

Comment: If I understand correctly the question is about could we specify AD account without specifying integrated security in the connection string. The answer is NO. We can do impersonation but that was not a part of the question.

Comment: True, but that's likely because the question, on it's own, is an XY problem. The OP thinks the problem is they can't use `Integrated Security = true`, where as they can, if they set the impersonation correctly. They haven't said they can't use `Integrated Security = true`, it's just that they want to test multiple accounts. Once they have impersonation configured, then the problem they're actually asking about goes away. Sometimes you need to read in between the lines of what the OP is asking, and attempt to solve the problem they have, not the question they are asking. :)

Comment: For example, someone is asking "Why isn't this dynamic SQL working, with a cannot convert to integer error? `SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + MyTable + ' WHERE ID = ' + @ID; EXEC @SQL;`" The solution isn't to change  + @ID to `+ CONVERT(varchar(3),@ID)` it's to parametrise the query; but that wasn't what the question was. ;)

Comment: The Impersonation has nothing with the connection string. So, the answer is NO. Impersonation is accomplished by switching WindowsIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

> Through Java eclipse ... Able to connect with Integrated Security = true ... But need try with other domains.

To connect using Windows Integrated Authentication to SQL Server using an account that you can't log on locally with or impersonate (ie an account from another domain), you can use [RUNAS /NETONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) or set an appropriate credential in the Windows Credential Manager.

In either case you configure a credential that will be used for NTLM authentication for network resources without requiring a local logon using those credentials. You would use `integratedSecurity=true` instead of providing credentials in the connection string.